# google drive api anchor to create comment on spreadsheet cell php

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

i want to create comment for google spreadsheet cell by api how can i do that

i have pass the anchor like that to insert comment on specific column of spreadsheet but it have inserted for sheet not pointing to the specific column

```
$APPPATH = dirname(__FILE__).'/google-api-php-client/';
set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__).'/google-api-php-client/src');

require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';


$client_email = 'xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
$private_key = file_get_contents('ServiceAccount-062591099ed0.p12');
$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $client_email,
    $scopes,
    $private_key
);
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$fileId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$comment_data=new Google_Service_Drive_Comment($client); 
$comment_data->content="hi comment on cell again & again"; 

$revisionId=$service->revisions->get($fileId, "head"); 

$matrix = array('r'=>$revisionId->id,'a'=>array((object)array('matrix'=>array('c'=>2,'r'=>2,'w'=>1,'h'=>1,'mw'=>100,'mh'=>100))));

 $std  = (object) $matrix;
 //echo json_encode($std);die;


$comment_data->anchor = $std; 
$service->comments->create($fileId, $comment_data,array('fields'=>'content'));
```

Comment: The Google drive api doesn't give you access to edit sheets. you need to use the sheets api https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Comment: @DaImTo I checked the docs of Sheetsv4 and found no mention of inserting commens using Sheets API. The most [relevant guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-comments) is found in Drive API which mentions inserting comments to spreadsheets by way of 'anchors' .

Comment: I still find this as an issue since I am not able to create an anchored comment in the Google Sheets. I can create a comment on a Google Sheet as a spreadsheet, but not on the specific cell even though I provide the anchor location